# is it possible to find all (java) "foreach" loops in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, foreach, intellij-idea, garbage-collection

For performance reasons (to reduce object allocation resulting from a bazillion calls to `ArrayList.iterator()`), I would like to replace all foreach loops with for loops, in my java project.

Replace:

```
List<SomeClass> items = createItems();
for (SomeClass item : items) {
    // do something with item
}
```

With:

```
SomeClass[] items = createItems();
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    SomeClass item = items[i];
    // do something with item
}
```

Is there a way to find all occurrences of foreach loops in a project?

Comment: You want to change data structures as well. You are changing List to array. Anyway what you want cannot be done in any IDE.

Comment: Are you sure it's impossible in all IDEs (that seems like a big call)? Also, though I do intend to, I don't actually *need* to change data structures: I could use `List.get(i)` instead of `Array[i]` and `List.size()` instead of `Array.length`. Though maybe searching for all occurrences of `List` then manually finding the foreach loops is the way to go

Comment: Yeah I meant IDE will not provide this functionality directly. You may have to write your own code to parse java file and replace. Or if it's possible manual search and replace.

Comment: In Eclipse you can do a global search by regexp. If you write your regexp correctly it should match only your foreach loops. It should be something similar in IntelliJ as well.

Comment: Not sure this works in IntellyJ, but in Eclipse you could set the source compatibility level to <1.5, then sort the error messages and look at all those complaining about foreach loops not being available yet.

Comment: @tobias_k this is a neat idea! :)

Comment: @tobias_k submit that as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: So you have ran your code through a profiler and it indicates to you that you have a performance problem because you are using the enhanced for loop? I am extremely skeptical...

Comment: @Michael I once did something similar and indeed the `foreach` loop seems to be a bit slower than regular `for` loops. Not by much, but if that loop is run thousands or millions of times, it might matter. Still, I agree that it should not be necessary to replace _all_ those loops.

Comment: @tobias_k It would be interesting to see how the iteration performance of Java 1.8's stream API compares to a standard for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to admit that I do not know IntelliJ much, but the following will work in Eclipse, and I assume that IntelliJ would have a similar feature.

The *for each* loop was introduced in Java 1.5, so one way to find all those loops would be to set the source level to e.g. 1.4. Then all those *foreach* loops (and other new language features) will provoke errors.

In Eclipse, go to *Preferences* (or the project's *Properties*), *Java Compiler*, and set the *Compiler Compliance Level* to *1.4*. Then, in the *Problems View*, you can sort the errors by their *Description* so all the "for each statement not available" errors line up nicely for you to find.

Again, my solution is for Eclipse, but I'm sure there is something similar in IntelliJ, too.

Comment: I can't try this right now but maybe there is a Quick Fix (Ctrl+1 or context menu) that does the actual change for you.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Good idea, but it seems like the only quick fix is to set the compliance level back to 1.5. Again, using Eclipse (Kepler)... maybe there is one in IntelliJ

Answer (score 4):

You can use structural search / replace (from menu Edit - > Find -> Structural ..., it's a built in plugin called "Structural search"):

Search template:

```
List<$TYPE$> $listVar$ = $init$;
for ($TYPE$ $var$ : $listVar$) {
    $BLOCK$;    
}
```

Replace template:

```
$TYPE$[] $listVar$ = $init$;
for (int i = 0; i < $listVar$.length; i++) {
    $TYPE$ $var$ = $listVar$[i];
    $BLOCK$;
}
```

You need to set unlimited number for $BLOCK$ variable to correctly process whole for block, or even fiddle little bit with regexp to catch lines that don't end with ;.

Note that this won't change return type of createItems() method ($init$ in the template). But you are left with bunch of compile time errors.

Comment: Neat. Does this also work when the whitespaces do not exactly match the template?

Comment: It definitely works for different indentations. I tried it for template where List... is not indented and it found List indented with 4 spaces.

Comment: I don't have that menu option, which version of IntelliJ IDEA are you using?

Comment: 13.1 ultimate, but the ultimate has had it as long as I remember (11+ at least).