# Automated translation of foreach loops to for loops

Tags: java, syntax

I'm looking for an IDE feature that will let me find all `foreach` loops with a certain type, e.g. `ArrayList`, like this:

```
for(String s: strList) {
    ...
}
```

And replace them with manually iterating loops, like:

```
String s;
for(int i = 0; i < strList.size(); i++) {
   s = strList.get(i);
   ...
}
```

I could use a regular expression to find `foreach` loops, but that wouldn't let me infer the type of `strList`.

How can I use my IDE to fix this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Compatibility with an older JRE?

Comment: Asking for an outside resource, tool, or library is off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Phrased slightly differently, it's an IDE question, though, which is very on-topic.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I've tried to rephrase it to be more on-topic.

Comment: You realize that this would be a *seriously* bad idea in the case of `LinkedList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IntelliJ has a feature that can do this for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110422/is-it-possible-to-find-all-java-foreach-loops-in-intellij-idea).

If you want something simpler than the solution outlined there (and you're okay with dealing with some amount of noise), you can also [turn the JRE version down to < 1.5](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) and wait for it to flag all of your `foreach` loops. There should be an option to auto-correct it to backwards-compatible syntax.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think that the question was off-topic as written, but on-topic with the change. I explained why in my comments on the question. The question linked is on-topic; phrased appropriately, this one is too. "Please recommend me a tool" is asking to be closed.